# Using react material-ui autocomplete with loading and freeSolo props

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have been using material-ui's [autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#autocomplete) in freeSolo mode. I would like to show a loading text while options are being loaded. It isn't working as expected currently. But loading text is shown when freeSolo is disabled. The same behaviour is seen for no-options text also. Is it possible to show loading and no options text in freeSolo mode?

Ref: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-mqtk8

In the above example, if freeSolo is set as false, loading text and no options text is shown as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Using this prop **loadingText** can you set your own loading text.

You can see this MaterialUi documentation, here is the link [Material UI AutoComlete API](https://v4.mui.com/api/autocomplete/#autocomplete-api)

```
 <Autocomplete
  freeSolo
  id="asynchronous-demo"
  style={{ width: 300 }}
  open={open}
  onOpen={() => {
    setOpen(true);
  }}
  onClose={() => {
    setOpen(false);
  }}
  getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.name === value.name}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
  options={options}
  loading={loading}
  loadingText="Your loading text here"
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      label="Asynchronous"
      fullWidth
      variant="outlined"
      InputProps={{
        ...params.InputProps,
        endAdornment: (
          <React.Fragment>
            {loading ? (
              <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} />
            ) : null}
            {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
          </React.Fragment>
        )
      }}
    />
  )}
/>
```